# dataframe conditional filter long list columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df
     c1    c2 P1
0  10.0  20.0 1
1   NaN  40.0 2
2  50.0   NaN 3
3   NaN   NaN 4
4  60.0  70.0 5
5   NaN   NaN 6
>>>
>>>
>>> cols = ["c1" , "c2"]
>>>
>>> df[df[cols[0]].notnull() | df[cols[1]].notnull()]
     c1    c2 P1
0  10.0  20.0 1
1   NaN  40.0 2
2  50.0   NaN 3
4  60.0  70.0 5
```

as shown above i am executing a logic in which i want to retain row which has atleast  one  non-Nan value.

Issue is that there can be as many as columns in list , like may be 100 or more . So How can i executed this logic in pythonic way?

Comment: What happen if first value in `c2` is `NaN` ?

Comment: @ jezrael row should not be dropped .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df=df.dropna(subset=[col],how='all')
```

Comment: there could be other columns in my dataframe which I do not want to drop based on logic. This logic accounts for some subset of columns which i assign in list

Comment: @BharatSharma - added to the osolution

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
df.dropna(subset=cols, how='all', inplace = True)
```

where `cols` is your:

```
cols = ["c1" , "c2"]
```